# Python get transformation matrix from two sets of points

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, regression, linear-algebra

I have to images, one simulation, one real data, with bright spots.

Simulation:
[image: Simulation]

Reality:
[image: reality]

I can detect the spots just fine and get the coordinates. Now I need to compute transformation matrix (scale, rotation, translation, maybe shear) between the two coordinate systems. If needed, I can pick some (5-10) corresponding points by hand to give to the algorithm

I tried a lot of approaches already, including:
2 implementations of ICP:
https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distICP/ICP-2.0.html#ICP

https://github.com/KojiKobayashi/iterative_closest_point_2d

Implementing affine transformations:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222113/given-3-points-of-a-rigid-body-in-space-how-do-i-find-the-corresponding-orienta/222170#222170

Implementations of affine transformations:
[Determining a homogeneous affine transformation matrix from six points in 3D using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546081/determining-a-homogeneous-affine-transformation-matrix-from-six-points-in-3d-usi?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[how to perform coordinates affine transformation using python? part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546182/how-to-perform-coordinates-affine-transformation-using-python-part-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Most of them simply fail somehow like this:
[image]
The red points are the spots from the simulation transformed into the reality - coordinate system.

The best approach so far is this one [how to perform coordinates affine transformation using python? part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546182/how-to-perform-coordinates-affine-transformation-using-python-part-2?answertab=votes#tab-top) yielding this:
[image]

As you see, the scaling and translating mostly works, but the image still needs to be rotated / mirrored.

Any ideas on how to get a working algorithm? If neccessary, I can provide my current non-working implementations, but they are basically as linked.

Comment: Looks like good enough data for me, so that it should work with some of these algorithms. Maybe try to provide better starting values (if there are starting values necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error.

I used `plt.imshow` to display both the simulated and real image and from there, pick the reference points from which to calculate the transformation.

Turns out, due to the usual array-to-image-index-flipping-voodoo (or a bad missunderstanding of the transformation on my side), I need to switch the x and y indices of the reference points from the simulated image.

With this, everything works fine using this [how to perform coordinates affine transformation using python? part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546182/how-to-perform-coordinates-affine-transformation-using-python-part-2?answertab=votes#tab-top)