# How to find affine transformation between two triangles (3 points) with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgimage

I have three pairs of the corresponding points for two CGImage. I want to find the affine transformation between these 3 pairs and apply this transformation to the second CGImage.
It's done with the code below using C++ and OpenCV. How can I apply it natively with Swift and CoreGraphics?

```
Mat warp_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
 warp_mat = getAffineTransform( srcTri, dstTri );

// Set the dst image the same type and size as src
 Mat  warp_dst = Mat::zeros( srcImg.rows, srcImg.cols, srcImg.type() );

/// Apply the Affine Transform just found to the src image
warpAffine( srcImg, warp_dst, warp_mat, warp_dst.size(), INTER_LINEAR );
```

Comment: You may have already found a solution to this point registration problem, but I've not (yet) found a good answer on StackOverflow--at least not for native Swift. I'd like code that would handle three or more point correspondences, and that wouldn't depend on OpenVN, and I believe others would benefit from such code as well. I hope to follow up within a few days with a solution. I believe I've found useful sample code, but need to pull that code together and test it.

Comment: I mean OpenCV, not "OpenVN."

Comment: I hope you figured this out. I'm looking forward to see your solution.

Comment: It's working for me, and I included enough code that you can paste it directly into a playground and test it. As I'll make clear in the answer I'm about to post, the first solution I'm using is specifically for 3 points. That's key. For a more general solution, such as those often used for point registration in image processing applications, the code is more involved. The code comments provide brief references to other techniques that I'll also write up in Swift, though I'm not sure when.

Comment: Some of the code seems to have been corrupted in copying & pasting. When I pasted the code from my answer back into a fresh playground, several errors popped up. I'll take a look at that again later. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Corrupted text fixed. There was a problem using "degrees < 90" in the function to check colinearity. Copying & pasting the code back into a new playground works for me now. Sorry for the holdup & the numerous messages.

Answer (score 4):

For the specific case of **3 points in 2D**, there is a solution called **Simplex Affine Mapping (SAM)** that I found fun to implement. It has several advantages:

- It can be implemented from scratch using only CoreGraphics (though I wrote a few simple extensions)
- The affine transform can be calculated by hand
- There are relatively few calculations to perform
- Whether you want to understand the math or not, it's straightforward to code the algorithm by following the authors' examples
- The code could be ported easily to other frameworks

There are some concerns using this technique for real-world image applications, but more about that below.

The SAM paper is **"Beginner’s guide to mapping simplexes aﬃnely"** by Tymchyshyn and Khlevniuk, uploaded to ResearchGate not quite two years ago:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely

A "workbook" paper from the same authors provides examples and step-by-step calculations:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely

The SAM formula relies on calculating the determinant of a 4x4 matrix divided by the determinant of a 3x3 matrix. The elements of the 4x4 matrix include vectors (representing points) and scalars.

The expression below yields the affine transform. **a**, **b**, **c** are 2D vectors for the first set of 3 points. **d**, **e**, **f** are 2D vectors for the second set of 3 points. **ax** and **ay** are the scalars for point/vector **a**. We solve for **p** and **q** and a translation component. I'll direct you back to the "workbook" paper for a proper description.

```
          |0  d   e   f   |
          |p  ax  bx  cx  |       // p called "x1" in the SAM paper
      det |q  ay  by  cy  |       // q called "x2" in the SAM paper
          |1  1   1   1   |
 (-1) ----------------------
             |ax  bx  cx  |      // ax = point A, x component
         det |ay  by  cy  |
             |1   1   1   |
```

What follows below is probably an excessive amount of code, but it's ready to paste into an XCode 12 playground and run. Toward the end there are test functions and examples of using those test functions.

The **sam()** function is key. Other code is there just to demonstrate the SAM technique. I would recommend rewriting the code to suit your purpose--feel free to swear at me and my Swift newbie code in the privacy of your home as you refactor. I included verbose comments in the hope that the code can stand alone. The links to the SAM papers are included in the comments for the SAM function.

Copy this whole chunk of code into an XCode 12 playground, run it, and see if you can make sense of the print statements.

```
import CoreGraphics
import Foundation       //for NumberFormatter, used in debug functions

// MARK: - Simple Affine Map function for 2D and supporting types

/// Calculate the affine transform from one set of three 2D points (the "from" triangle) to another set of three 2D points (the "to" triangle).
/// Throws an error if one of the sets of points is colinear.
/// The transform is calculated using the 2D expression of the Simplex Affine Map [SAM] by V. B. Tymchyshyn and A. V. Khlevniuk.
/// https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely
///
/// The workbook from the authors provides numerous examples showing step-by-step calculation for simplexes in N dimensions.
/// https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely\
///
/// A triangle is a simplex in 2D space, and hence works using the SAM scheme.
/// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex
///
/// The matrix elements include a mix of vectors and scalars. For this code, use letter names corresponding to the vectors and scalars in the SAM paper.
/// a, b, c are 2D points in the "from" triangle
/// d, e, f are 2D points in the "to" triangle
///
///          |0  d   e   f   |
///          |p  ax  bx  cx  |       // p called "x1" in the SAM paper
///      det |q  ay  by  cy  |       // q called "x2" in the SAM paper
///          |1  1   1   1   |
/// (-1) ----------------------
///             |ax  bx  cx  |      // ax = point A, x component
///         det    |ay  by  cy  |
///             |1   1   1   |
///
/// For image processing applications this technique may not be appropriate if point finding is not sufficiently repeatable.
/// This mapping will be sensitive to noise / inaccuracy in finding any of the "from" or "to" points: any triangle can map to any other triangle!
/// For point registration, typically more than 3 point correspondences are used. The transform may be found
/// using a least squares fitting, and often by eliminating outlier points. Related topics include Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) and
/// Random Sampling and Consensus (RANSAC).
func sam(from: Triangle, to: Triangle) throws -> CGAffineTransform {
    if from.colinear() {
        throw SamError.colinearPoints(description: "Points in 'from' triangle are colinear. Can not calculate SAM transform.")
    }
    
    if to.colinear() {
        throw SamError.colinearPoints(description: "Points in 'to' triangle are colinear. Can not calculate SAM transform.")
    }
    
    let a = from.vector1
    let b = from.vector2
    let c = from.vector3
    
    let d = to.vector1
    let e = to.vector2
    let f = to.vector3

    // Determinant of 4x4 in numerator of SAM formula
    // Reduce to p, q, and translation. (p, q) here are (x1, x2) in the SAM paper.
    // We can find the determinant starting with any row or any column, so we make it easy to isolate p ("x1") and q ("x2")
    
    // +0 * (...)
    
    // -p ( [d] (by - cy) - [e] (ay - cy) + [f] (ay - by) )
    let p = CGFloat(-1.0) * (d * (b.dy - c.dy) - e * (a.dy - c.dy) + f * (a.dy - b.dy))
    
    // +q ( [d] (bx - cx) - [e] (ax - cx) + [f] (ax - bx) )
    let q = d * (b.dx - c.dx) - e * (a.dx - c.dx) + f * (a.dx - b.dx)
    
    // -1  ( [d] (bx * cy - by * cx) - [e] (ax * cy - ay * cx) + [f] * (ax * by - ay * bx) )
    let translation =  CGFloat(-1.0) * (d * (b.dx * c.dy - b.dy * c.dx) - e * (a.dx * c.dy - a.dy * c.dx) + f * (a.dx * b.dy - a.dy * b.dx))
    
    // Determinant of 3x3 used in denominator of SAM formula
    let denominator = determinant(from)
    
    let pd = CGFloat(-1.0) * p / denominator
    let qd = CGFloat(-1.0) * q / denominator
    let td = CGFloat(-1.0) * translation / denominator
    
    // plug values into CoreGraphics affine transform
    //  |a  b   0|   =  |pd.x   pd.y    0|
    //  |c  d   0|      |qd.x   qd.y    0|
    //  |tx ty  1|      |td.x   td.y    1|
    
    return CGAffineTransform(a: pd.dx, b: pd.dy, c: qd.dx, d: qd.dy, tx: td.dx, ty: td.dy)
}

enum SamError: Error {
    case colinearPoints(description: String)
}

/// Three points nominally defining a triangle, but possibly colinear.
struct Triangle {
    var point1: CGPoint
    var point2: CGPoint
    var point3: CGPoint
    
    var x1: CGFloat { point1.x }
    var y1: CGFloat { point1.y }
    var x2: CGFloat { point2.x }
    var y2: CGFloat { point2.y }
    var x3: CGFloat { point3.x }
    var y3: CGFloat { point3.y }
    
    /// Point1 as a 2D vector
    var vector1: CGVector { CGVector(point1) }
    
    /// Point2 as a 2D vector
    var vector2: CGVector { CGVector(point2) }
    
    /// Point3 as a 2D vector
    var vector3: CGVector { CGVector(point3) }
    
    /// Return a Triangle after applying an affine transform to self.
    func applying(_ t: CGAffineTransform) -> Triangle {
        Triangle(
            point1: self.point1.applying(t),
            point2: self.point2.applying(t),
            point3: self.point3.applying(t)
        )
    }
    
    init(point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, point3: CGPoint) {
        self.point1 = point1
        self.point2 = point2
        self.point3 = point3
    }
    
    init(x1: CGFloat, y1: CGFloat, x2: CGFloat, y2: CGFloat, x3: CGFloat, y3: CGFloat) {
        point1 = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y1)
        point2 = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y2)
        point3 = CGPoint(x: x3, y: y3)
    }
    
    /// Returns a (Bool, CGFloat) tuple indicating whether the points in the Triangle are colinear, and the angle between vectors tested.
    func colinear(degreesTolerance: CGFloat = 0.5) -> Bool {
        let v1 = vector2 - vector1
        let v2 = vector3 - vector2
        let radians = CGVector.angleBetweenVectors(v1: v1, v2: v2)
        
        if radians.isNaN {
            return true
        }
        
        var degrees = radiansToDegrees(radians)
        
        if degrees > 90 {
           degrees = 180 - degrees
        }

        // code to get around parsing error
        return 0 > degrees - degreesTolerance
    }
}

func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    degrees * CGFloat.pi / 180.0
}

func radiansToDegrees(_ radians: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    180.0 * radians / CGFloat.pi
}

extension CGVector {
    init(_ point: CGPoint) {
        self.init(dx: point.x, dy: point.y)
    }
    
    static func + (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: lhs.dx + rhs.dx, dy: lhs.dy + rhs.dy)
    }

    static func - (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: lhs.dx - rhs.dx, dy: lhs.dy - rhs.dy)
    }

    static func * (_ vector: CGVector, _ scalar: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: vector.dx * scalar, dy: vector.dy * scalar)
    }
    
    static func * (_ scalar: CGFloat, _ vector: CGVector) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: vector.dx * scalar, dy: vector.dy * scalar)
    }

    static func * (lhs: CGVector, rhs: CGVector) -> CGFloat {
        lhs.dx * rhs.dx + lhs.dy * rhs.dy
    }
    
    static func dotProduct(v1: CGVector, v2: CGVector) -> CGFloat {
        v1.dx * v2.dx + v1.dy * v2.dy
    }
    
    static func / (_ vector: CGVector, _ scalar: CGFloat) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: vector.dx / scalar, dy: vector.dy / scalar)
    }

    static func / (_ scalar: CGFloat, _ vector: CGVector) -> CGVector {
        CGVector(dx: vector.dx / scalar, dy: vector.dy / scalar)
    }
    
    // Returns again between vectors in range 0 to 2 * pi [positive]
    // a * b = ||a|| ||b|| cos(theta)
    // theta = arc cos (a * b / ||a|| ||b||)
    static func angleBetweenVectors(v1: CGVector, v2: CGVector) -> CGFloat {
        acos( v1 * v2 / (v1.length() * v2.length()) )
    }
    
    func length() -> CGFloat {
        sqrt(self.dx * self.dx + self.dy * self.dy)
    }
}

/// Determinant of three points used in the denominator of the SAM formula.
/// x1   x2  x3
/// y1   y2  y3
/// 1    1   1
func determinant(_ t: Triangle) -> CGFloat {
    t.x1 * (t.y2 - t.y3) - t.x2 * (t.y1 - t.y3) + t.x3 * (t.y1 - t.y2)
}

//MARK: - Debug
extension NumberFormatter {
    func string(_ value: CGFloat, digits: Int, failText: String = "[?]") -> String {
        minimumFractionDigits = max(0, digits)
        maximumFractionDigits = minimumFractionDigits
        
        guard let s = string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(value))) else {
            return failText
        }
        
        return s
    }
    
    func string(_ point: CGPoint, digits: Int = 1, failText: String = "[?]") -> String {
        let sx = string(point.x, digits: digits, failText: failText)
        let sy = string(point.y, digits: digits, failText: failText)
        return "(\(sx), \(sy))"
    }
    
    func string(_ vector: CGVector, digits: Int = 1, failText: String = "[?]") -> String {
        let sdx = string(vector.dx, digits: digits, failText: failText)
        let sdy = string(vector.dy, digits: digits, failText: failText)
        return "(\(sdx), \(sdy))"
    }
    
    func string(_ transform: CGAffineTransform, rotationDigits: Int = 2, translationDigits: Int = 1, failText: String = "[?]") -> String {
        let sa = string(transform.a, digits: rotationDigits)
        let sb = string(transform.b, digits: rotationDigits)
        let sc = string(transform.c, digits: rotationDigits)
        let sd = string(transform.d, digits: rotationDigits)
        let stx = string(transform.tx, digits: translationDigits)
        let sty = string(transform.ty, digits: translationDigits)

        var s = "a:  \(sa)   b: \(sb)   0"
        s += "\nc:  \(sc)   d: \(sd)   0"
        s += "\ntx: \(stx)   ty: \(sty)   1"
        return s
    }
}

let formatter = NumberFormatter()

/// Checks whether the three points in the Triangle are colinear.
/// Returns a test message spanning multiple lines.
func testColinearity(_ t: Triangle) -> String {
    let co = t.colinear()
    let st1 = formatter.string(t.point1, digits: 2)
    let st2 = formatter.string(t.point2, digits: 2)
    let st3 = formatter.string(t.point3, digits: 2)
    
    var s = "\(st1), \(st2), \(st3): points in triangle"
    s += "\n\(co): colinear"

    return s
}

/// Checks how close two points are. Used to test whether a transformed point (actual) is equivalent to the expected point.
/// Returns a test message spanning multiple lines.
func testCoincidence(actual: CGPoint, expected: CGPoint, pointTolerance: CGFloat = 0.1) -> String {
    let vector = CGVector(actual) - CGVector(expected)
    let distance = vector.length()
    let sd = formatter.string(distance, digits: 2)
    let sa = formatter.string(actual, digits: 2)
    let se = formatter.string(expected, digits: 2)
    
    return "\(sd) offset  from actual \(sa) to expected \(se)"
}

/// Calculates the affine transform and checks its validity.
/// Returns a test message spanning multiple lines.
func testSAM(from t1: Triangle, to t2: Triangle, pointTolerance: CGFloat = 0.1) -> String {
    var s = "from \(t1) to \(t2)"

    do {
        let transform = try sam(from: t1, to: t2)
        s += "\n" + formatter.string(transform)

        // apply transform to points in t1
        let a = t1.applying(transform)

        // get difference between transformed points (actual) and t2 points (expected)
        s += "\n" + testCoincidence(actual: a.point1, expected: t2.point1, pointTolerance: pointTolerance)
        s += "\n" + testCoincidence(actual: a.point2, expected: t2.point2, pointTolerance: pointTolerance)
        s += "\n" + testCoincidence(actual: a.point3, expected: t2.point3, pointTolerance: pointTolerance)

        return s
    }
    catch SamError.colinearPoints(let description) {
        return description
    }
    catch {
        return error.localizedDescription
    }
}

//MARK: - Tests for Playground
print()
print("** Colinearity tests **")
let c1 = Triangle(x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 2, y2: 2, x3: 3, y3: 3)
let sc1 = testColinearity(c1)
print(sc1)

print()
let c2 = Triangle(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 5, y2: 5, x3: 0.01, y3: 0.02)
let sc2 = testColinearity(c2)
print(sc2)

print()
let c3 = Triangle(x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 2, y2: 3, x3: 3, y3: 2)
let sc3 = testColinearity(c3)
print(sc3)

print()
print("** Arbitrary translation example from SAM workbook **")
let a1 = Triangle(x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: 2, y2: 3, x3: 3, y3: 2)
let a2 = Triangle(x1: 3, y1: 2, x2: 1, y2: 5, x3: -2, y3: 1)
print(testColinearity(a1))
print()
print(testColinearity(a2))
print()
print(testSAM(from: a1, to: a2))

print()
print("** Pure Translation **")
let t1 = Triangle(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: -2, y2: 3, x3: -5, y3: 3)
let t2 = Triangle(x1: 3, y1: -2, x2: 1, y2: 1, x3: -2, y3: 1)
print(testSAM(from: t1, to: t2))

print()
print("** Rotation and Translation **")
let r1 = Triangle(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, x3: 0, y3: 1)
let r2 = Triangle(x1: 6, y1: 5, x2: 5, y2: 5, x3: 6, y3: 4)
print(testSAM(from: r1, to: r2))

print()
print("** Pure Scaling **")
let s1 = Triangle(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0, x3: 0, y3: 1)
let s2 = Triangle(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 5, y2: 0, x3: 0, y3: 5)
print(testSAM(from: s1, to: s2))

print()
print("** Test in which a triangle has colinear points")
let k1 = Triangle(x1: 1, y1: 1, x2: -2, y2: -2, x3: 5, y3: 5)
let k2 = Triangle(x1: -5, y1: 3, x2: 2, y2: 8, x3: -3, y3: 1)
print()
print(testColinearity(k1))
print()
print(testColinearity(k2))
print()
print(testSAM(from: k1, to: k2))
```

**More General Techniques**

You've used OpenCV, so you're probably aware of algorithms like [SIFT](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html) and [AKAZE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d30/classcv_1_1AKAZE.html) that can use many thousands of correspondences, that rely on RANSAC or other techniques to discard outliers, and so on. Those are robust techniques.

Just 3 point pairs can work well, but often times folks want a more generalized technique that can accept an arbitrarily long list of correspondences, work magic on them, and yield a good transform despite the presence of noise.

Originally I started looking for native Swift code that relied on Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), RANSAC, and the like. Although there is no SVD function I found in the iOS frameworks, there *is* a sample project that includes an SVD function and supporting types. It uses the [Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate) framework. One day I may post a follow-up answer that borrows the SVD function from this project:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/denoising_an_image_using_linear_algebra

Though I've only quickly skimmed the denoising project, built it, and run it once, I understand that somewhere underneath the code relies (or at least could run) on [LAPACK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK).

For those new to the subject, there are StackOverflow posts on more general solutions:

[Finding translation and scale on two sets of points to get least square error in their distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432805/finding-translation-and-scale-on-two-sets-of-points-to-get-least-square-error-in)

Finally, a Wikipedia article that summarizes a variety of methods for mapping one set of points to another:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration

Comment: For the more traditional method, see this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. I was planning to use it for face alignment (aligning outer eyes and nose) before giving it to the Openface model. I successfully applied it using your implementation. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: You're most welcome! This could be written more efficiently using matrix types in SIMD, and some people may prefer the more traditional method. I used SIMD code for affine + perspective transforms here: https://rethunk.medium.com/perspective-transform-from-quadrilateral-to-quadrilateral-in-swift-5a9adf2175c3. Aside from that, one of the authors of the SAM paper was glad I promoted their work.